# Not receiving notifications for AWS S3 PUT event for large files

Tags: events, amazon-s3

I have enabled S3 event property for notifying PUT events. I used AWS console for doing this. I forward it to AWS lambda for further processing. But S3 didn't notify when I upload files with large size.

I have uploaded 5 files, 3 of them are of smaller size and 2 files of size 17.4MB and 61.9MB. S3 didn't notify PUT event of these larger files. I got notified about other 3 files of size less than 1MB.

I have tried S3 event notification with AWS SNS also for checking whether the problem is with S3 event notifier or with my lambda function. At this time also I didn't get notified about those 2 large files.

I also enable S3 delete event with SNS for testing. In that case, it worked. I got email via SNS about the event. But the problem is with the PUT event.

So, is that a problem with S3 or do I miss anything while setting up S3 event notification?

Thanks.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

These are the different event types that can be triggered when a file is created on S3:

```
s3:ObjectCreated:Put

s3:ObjectCreated:Post

s3:ObjectCreated:Copy

s3:ObjectCreated:CompleteMultipartUpload
```

Smaller file uploads will trigger an `s3:ObjectCreated:Put` event. Larger file uploads will trigger an `s3:ObjectCreated:CompleteMultipartUpload` event. So you need to add the `s3:ObjectCreated:CompleteMultipartUpload` event type to your trigger. You can also set it to `s3:ObjectCreated:*` to receive all the object created events.